# Rails has_many through, issues with foreign key and source

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `User` has many subscribers and many publishers, both of which are users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "subscriber_id"
    has_many :subscribers, :through => :relationships, :source => :subscriber

    has_many :inverse_relationships, :class_name => "Relationship", :foreign_key => "publisher_id"
    has_many :publishers, :through => :inverse_relationships, :source => :publisher

    def subscribe_to(publisher)
        self.relationships.create!(publisher_id: publisher.id, subscriber_id: id)
    end
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
    belongs_to :publisher, :class_name => "User"
end
```

A user's publishers is who the user is *subscribed to.*

However, if I do `john.subscribe_to(a_publisher)`, and then attempt to `puts john.publishers`, I get back an empty array.

I'm going back and forth randomly changing the foreign key and the source, hoping that it will eventually work, but something is off. What should the sources and foreign keys be here?

### Update

Here's what I did to make it work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "publisher_id"
    has_many :subscribers, :through => :relationships, :source => :subscriber

    has_many :inverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "subscriber_id", :class_name => "Relationship"
    has_many :publishers, :through => :inverse_relationships, :source => :publisher

    def subscribe_to(publisher)
        publisher.relationships.create!(subscriber_id: id)
    end
end
```

First, I switched the foreign keys for both. Second, and this is the part I don't understand, I changed

```
self.relationships.create!(publisher_id: publisher.id)
```

to

```
publisher.relationships.create!(subscriber_id: id)
```

and it worked. For some reason, it doesn't work the other way around. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Where or What is your `subscribe_to` method ?

Comment: @bobbystouket it's in there

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your association seems strange. You should try like this:

```
 has_many :subscribers, :through => :relationships, :class_name => 'User'
```

And call :

```
 john.subscribers.create(a_publisher)
```

Nowhere you're saying that `subscriber` is a `User`. I think your problem comes from here.

Maybe you can try with: `:source => :user`

Comment: `john.subscribers.create(a_publisher)` is backwards. It should be something like `john.publishers.create(a_publisher)`.

Comment: It's true. By the way, I'm sure that your problem comes from `:source => :subscriber`
If you take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) at the paragraph **4.2.2.8 :source** you can have more details.

Can you add the SQL request made when you search `puts john.publishers` ?

Comment: I had a similar issue about the order. I don't have any explanation. Thank you for sharing the solution.